# How to place a wildcard character in a bash string

Tags: bash

I have a directory `USR/SRC/Code`and since the use is different for everyone and people can place this anywhere in their work space I want to make it so that as long as SRC/Code is available in the directory for it to work such as `*/SRC/Code`here is what I have tried and has not worked:

```
#!/bin/bash

    DIRECTORY="/SRC/Code"
    if [ -d "\*$DIRECTORY" ]; then
        # Will enter here if $DIRECTORY exists, even if it contains spaces
            echo "TRUE"
    fi

#!/bin/bash

DIRECTORY="*/SRC/Code"
if [ -d "\$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    # Will enter here if $DIRECTORY exists, even if it contains spaces
        echo "TRUE"
fi


#!/bin/bash

DIRECTORY="\*/SRC/Code"
if [ -d "\$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    # Will enter here if $DIRECTORY exists, even if it contains spaces
        echo "TRUE"
fi
```

Comment: Can you give some examples about where that directory might be? Can it exist arbitrarily deep below the current directory?

Comment: Yes the folders can exist beep below the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globs can match multiple files, so it's better to store them in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob globstar    # Enable recursion and zero matching
directories=( **/SRC/Code )
case "${#directories[@]}" in
    1) echo "Found the directory: ${directories[0]}" ;;
    0) echo "There were no matches..." ;;
    *) echo "There was more than one match!" ;;
esac
```

Comment: I get the impression you'll also want `globstar` and look for `**/SRC/Code/`, but let's see what the OP has to say.

Comment: I ended up using the globstar and added in andother * as said in the previous comment. I just don't understand the 1 0 *. In my case if the directory is not found I want to print out that the script is now exiting and the use needs to run another script to create that directory before running this script

Comment: @that, please add some explanation so Alex understands what's going on

Comment: Also this code only works for finding more than one match, I can put **/Does/Not/Exist which isnt a directory and it says it found the directory

Comment: @AlexThomson Make sure the nullglob option is set as in the example, and that you're running it with bash and not sh.